# In clan wars, on the war map, what do the troops standing outside the base represent?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When looking through the various townhalls, some of the bases have one barb, some have two and some have none. What do these represent?

Comment: On the war map, when selecting a base to attack, some bases have one troop standing outside, others have two, others have none. What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In Clash of Clans some townhalls have barbarians in place to signify your **Unused attacks.**

Basically, those are the amount of attacks you have left. Each barbarian is equal to one attack.

You can attack the other clans with your troops, but you can't use any more barbarians (e.g. attacks) than you have.

[Source](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/250091-What-do-the-little-barbarians-mean-in-clan-wars-overview)

Comment: More clarification? I don't understand

Comment: @Sparrow Basically, each barbarian represents the amount of attacks you have left. You can attack the other clans with your troops, but you can't use any more barbarians (e.g. attacks) than you have.

Comment: I thought they meant that you have troops in your clan castle.. thanks @Chantola for making this clear.

Comment: @Neffer_23 I thought it meant that the ENEMY had troops left at their base after being attacked.

Comment: @Sparow well, yea thats what i mean about in your clan castle

Comment: is this feature removed or something?

Comment: @Esq no it is still in the game some people just might have used their attacks if there are no Barbarians left.

Answer (score 2):

The barbarian standing beside the town hall in war represents the attacks you have left in war.  When you attack you will lose a barbarian.  When you have no more barbarians standing beside the town hall, you can't attack.